# How to print matrix of a graph in R language

Tags: r, matrix, adjacency-matrix

After loading external graph from disk as edgelist, I want to view the matrix format of this graph. Here is my steps:

```
> rm(list=ls())
> data <- read.graph("c:\\temp\\graph.txt", format="edgelist")
> adjm <- data.matrix(data)
> adjm
IGRAPH D--- 18 28 -- 
> 

> get.incidence(data)
Error in get.incidence(data) : 
  Not a bipartite graph, supply `types' argument
```

The matrix is not print. The data format of external graph is like(graph.txt):

```
0 7
2 7
3 0 
3 2 
3 4 
4 9
5 1 
5 6
6 7
7 12
8 2 
8 3
8 14
10 6
11 12
12 13
13 8
14 15
14 13
```

As you can see, it only print graph information(number of nodes, direct or undirect). How can I print this graph as **incidence matrix**?  or how can I supply types for incidence command? Thanks

Comment: Try `get.edgelist(data)`.

Comment: Then how to process get.edgelist result?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question - see below for a solution using `igraph`.

Answer (score 1):

The `igraph` functions make this very straightforward.

```
g <- graph.ring(10)
g

IGRAPH U--- 10 10 -- Ring graph
+ attr: name (g/c), mutual (g/x), circular (g/x)

get.adjacency(g)

10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 [1,] . 1 . . . . . . . 1
 [2,] 1 . 1 . . . . . . .
 [3,] . 1 . 1 . . . . . .
 [4,] . . 1 . 1 . . . . .
 [5,] . . . 1 . 1 . . . .
 [6,] . . . . 1 . 1 . . .
 [7,] . . . . . 1 . 1 . .
 [8,] . . . . . . 1 . 1 .
 [9,] . . . . . . . 1 . 1
[10,] 1 . . . . . . . 1 .
```

Wrap `get.adjacency` in `as.matrix` if you'd like it coerced to a binary `matrix`.

Comment: This print adjacency matrix, but how about incidence matrix?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure of the correct way to overcome your `Not a bipartite graph` error. You need to correctly specify a `type` argument (a binary vector the same length as the number of vertices in your graph), but I don't know how to determine this. Feel free to "unaccept" this answer, since it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 2-column matrix M, then we can create a square matrix of 0s and fill it with 1s at connected nodes by

```
M <- M + 1
adj <- matrix(0, max(M), max(M))
adj[M] <- 1
```

Comment: This one also works for adjacency matrix after made minor changes adj[m] <- 1. But how about incidence matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Usage

```
get.incidence(your_graph, types = NULL, ......)
```

> types:     An optional vertex type vector to use instead of the type
>   vertex attribute. You must supply this argument if the graph has no
>   type vertex attribute

let's call the data frame as "your_data_frame" and your graph as "your_graph"

It looks like the graph you created has type not specified. It looks like below

```
> your_graph
IGRAPH DN-- 65 333 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):
```

A graph where type is specified as bipartite looks like

```
> your_graph
IGRAPH DN-B 92 22325 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), type (v/l)
+ edges (vertex names):
```

B in DN-B stands for bipartite

To specify the type do the following

```
V(your_graph)$type = V(your_graph)$name %in% your_data_frame[,1]
```

Note: your_data_frame should only have two columns. if not use quick indexing like df[c(1,2)]

after performing these steps you can check your_graph, now type should be specified

you can then go ahead and create the incidence matrix using